# Is it possible to desregard 'out' parameters?

Tags: c#, methods, out-parameters

I've got a method like this...

```
public List<String> TestMethod(Int32 parameter, out Boolean theOutParameter)
{
}
```

When I call the method, if I'm not interested in `theOutParameter` what would the call to the method look like? Seems a bit excessive to instance a new `bool` just so that the out parameter of a method is dealt with if I'm not interested in the value.

Answer (score 6):

No, but you can add an overload:

```
public List<string> TestMethod(int parameter)
{
    bool tmp;
    return TestMethod(parameter, out tmp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll create the temp var and go with that if there's no other way around it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to desregard 'out' parameters?

No, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

You could choose to return your own list that has a property that states if there are more results 
e.g.

```
public class QueryResult:List<string>
{
    public bool HasMoreResults{get;set;}
}

public QueryResult TestMethod(Int32 parameter)
{
    QueryResult res;
    //create list, filling, etc.
    //instead of setting the out, set the parameter
    res.HasMoreResults = ....
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to remove `theOutParameter` from the signature?

Comment: @MarcGravell Oops, you're right, the dangers of copy/pasting while answering the phone. Thanks for the head's up, I've altered the code